# Round down to nearest quarter hour

Tags: google-sheets

I have a timesheet which I use for billing clients. It records entries from Toggl as hour fractions, ie 35 minutes is recorded as 0.58. I want to round this number down to the nearest 0.25, ie. the nearest quarter hour. Is this possible in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit more reading, the function I was looking for is MROUND, to round to the nearest given fraction. eg.

```
=MROUND(A1,0.25)
```

The crucial step required is to add or substract half a step depending on whether you want it round up or down, eg.

```
Up: =MROUND(A1+0.125;0.25)
Down: =MROUND(A1-0.125;0.25)
```

**Added screenshots for clarity**:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After many tries with `ROUND` and `MROUND` I could only get it to work with `FLOOR` (rounds down) and `CEILING` (rounds up).

The following example rounds down to the nearest half hour:

`=FLOOR(A1, 1/96)`

**1/24** for an hour, **1/48** for half an hour etc.

The last thing to do is change the `Format` of the field to `time` to get a proper time format:

`00:00:00`

Comment: Alternative to settings Format to Time would be to wrap in Text function such as `=TEXT(FLOOR(A1, 1/96), 'h:mm:ss')`